# Swiper Slider: How to disable "swiping" and "mouse wheel scrolling" during the transition?

Tags: swiper.js

I have a question about the [Swiper Slider](https://swiperjs.com/). Is it possible to disable "swiping" and "mouse wheel scrolling" if the transition starts, and enable it again if the transition end? Something like that. This is to prevent the user from scrolling or swiping too fast between slides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By API parameter:
`preventInteractionOnTransition: true;`

(`false` by default).

> When enabled it **won't allow** changing slides by swiping or
> navigation/pagination buttons during transition https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how I skipped it. :)